# Rails: is there a way to add associations via the command line?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, command-line, model

In the [Rails documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_many-association), we find the following example:

```
class Physician < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :appointments
  has_many :patients, :through => :appointments
end
```

I'm just curious: is it possible to generate this via the command line using `rails generate model`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not according to the usage message you get from `rails generate model`. You can set up a `belongs_to` relationship, though:

```
rails generate model photo title:string album:references
```

Gives me the following in `app/models/photo.rb`:

```
class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :album
end
```

Comment: Thanks. So could I still use the `generate` command and then simply add the `has_many` and `:through` associations manually before migrating? Is there anything that would need to be changed in the auto-generated migration file?

Comment: Nope. With `has_many`, the foreign keys are in the other table. You only need to add a column when you're doing a `belongs_to` relation.